Vercel Won't Build Jekyll's SCSS Properly
It works locally on my machine, but Vercel won't build it properly. I'm trying to deploy a simple one-page Jekyll website. This is the deployment logs:
Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/style.scss':
                    Invalid US-ASCII character "\xE2" on line 5

I've already tried fixing line 5 on the SCSS and what would be the CSS, when it's converted. I honestly don't know what the ASCII character there is.
Here's the SCSS:
---
---
/* http://mrbacay.com/
   v0.1 | 20190114
   License: Creative Commons
*/

body {
  background-color: #0D0D0D;
  color: #736B65;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  color: #FFFF00;
}

#guide {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Space Mono", monospace;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%,50%);
}

Please, help?

I already did 'ga' in Vim to check the ASCII character and it ouputed null.

I also did this bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux already because of this https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/4269
